# Find unbiased estimator of the shifted exponential distribution with rate 1

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

So the pdf would be $f(x)=\exp({-(x-\theta)})$.

The most natural estimator $X_{(1)}=\min\{X_1,\ldots, X_n\}$ but I'm having trouble finding what the unbiased estimator would be.

I tried finding the pdf of $X_{(1)}$ and then taking the expectation but I'm getting something super strange for the pdf so I'm wondering if this is the right approach or where I may be going wrong.

Comment: The probability that the minimum is **greater** than $t$ is the probability they are all greater than $t$. The probability any one is greater than $t$ is obtained by integrating your density function from $t$ to infinity, easy. To find the probability they are all greater than $t$ take the $n$-th power. The probability the min is $\le t$ is obtained by subtracting from $1$. Now differentiate to find the pdf, be careful not to make a minus sign error.  Now for the mean do the usual thing. It will be an integration by parts.

Comment: Don't forget that you are integrating from $\theta$ to $\infty$. I have written the general outline, and hope it will be enough for you to carry out the calculation. It is a little messy, so there are unfortunately opportunities for error.

Comment: The expectation of Y=min{X1,....Xn} is theta+1/n hence Y-1/n is an unbiased estimator of theta. It would help if you showed the *super strange* thing that you found for the PDF of Y.

Answer (score 1):

So I assume that it is proven $x_{(1)}$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

The order statistics gives that the pdf for $x_{(1)}$ is 
$$f_{x_{(1)}}(x) = ne^{-n(x-\theta)}, x \ge \theta$$

Let us perform the expectation. 
$$E(x_{(1)}) = \int_\theta^{\infty} xne^{-n(x-\theta)}dx = e^{n\theta} \cdot \int_\theta^{\infty} xne^{-nx}dx$$
$$=e^{n\theta} \Big\{[-xe^{-nx}]_\theta^\infty +\int_\theta^\infty e^{-nx}dx \Big\} = e^{n\theta} \cdot \theta e^{-n\theta} + e^{n\theta} \Big[-\frac{1}{n}e^{-nx}\Big]_\theta^\infty = \theta +\frac{1}{n}$$

Therefore, we take $E(x_{(1)}-\frac{1}{n}) = (\theta+\frac{1}{n}) - \frac{1}{n} = \theta$.
Hence, $x_{(1)}-\frac{1}{n}$ is an unbiased estimator for $\theta$.

This has been a long post but hope it is worthy.